# neuralnet error

Tags: r, caret

I am trying to train a `neuralnet` model by using `caret` package by this command:

```
model.neuralnet <- train(X, Y, method='neuralnet', trControl=myControl, 
    stepmax=700, rep=1, learningrate=0.05, algorithm = 'backprob', 
    preProcess=PP, tuneGrid = expand.grid(.layer1=4, .layer2=1, .layer3=1), 
    act.fct = 'tanh', linear.output = TRUE)
```

`X`, `Y` are correct inputs, `myControl` should be proper settings, because I build in same session successfully other models with them. After every second output on console it writes something like this (I have repeated CV but folds must be OK, because other models had no problems...):

```
model fit failed for Fold02.Rep1: layer1=4, layer2=1, layer3=1
```

In the end of the computations with above command I get:

```
Aggregating results
Selecting tuning parameters
Fitting layer1 = numeric(0), layer2 = numeric(0), layer3 = numeric(0) on full training set
Error in if (tuneValue$.layer1 == 0) stop("the first layer must have at least one hidden unit") : 
argument is of length zero
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Timing stopped at: 0.16 0 0.15
```

But I think I do not have set `layer1` to zero (`tuneValue$.layer1 == 0`). Please - were I am doing mistake?

Milan

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
tuneGrid = expand.grid(.layer1=4, .layer2=1, .layer3=1)
```

To:

```
tuneGrid = expand.grid(.layer1=c(4), .layer2=c(1), .layer3=c(1))
```

The issue happens when `expand.grid` asks for a series of sequences as oppose to a sequence of integers.